# How to generate a nonce and print it on client side in Android?

Tags: java, android, client-server

I am now working on a program for Android which is something related to IMS.
I want the server to send back a nonce to the client as a string and print it on the client-side.

Part of my code, from [Generating a Secure Random Number](https://web.archive.org/web/20121014123119/http://exampledepot.com/egs/java.security/CreateSecureRandom.html):

```
public static String generateNonce() { 
  try {
   // Create a secure random number generator
   SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");

   // Get 1024 random bits
   byte[] bytes = new byte[1024/8];
   sr.nextBytes(bytes);

   // Create two secure number generators with the same seed
   int seedByteCount = 10;
   byte[] seed = sr.generateSeed(seedByteCount);

   sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
   sr.setSeed(seed);
   SecureRandom sr2 = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
   sr2.setSeed(seed);
   } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
  }
  //return NONCE;
  return null;
 }
```

I declared `NONCE = generateNonce();` in the beginning.
But the problem is instead of getting a nonce value, it prints *null* on the client-side. When I tried to print it on the server-side, it also appears to be *null*.

Can someone enlighten me on the error in my code or help me with better or more suitable coding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the `return` statement to the value you'd like to return, as of now your code *generates* (or seems to generate) the NONCE but you return `null` so the String `NONCE` is given a value of `null`.

You should also remove the `return null` statement. If you leave it in and it's the *last* return statement, your code will generate a valid NONCE **but** will return `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'd sort out the format of your code first as it is pretty unreadable.

Then I would remove the second SecureRandom instance.

Then I would remove the `return null;` statement at the end.

Then I would rewrite the function to return a random integer like this:

```
 return sr.next(32);
```

Also making sure that the function is declared to return an integer rather than a string.